# How to forbid creation of new class attributes in Python?

Tags: python, attributes

This may appear as a very basic question, but I couldn't find anything helpful on SO or elsewhere...

If you take built-in classes, such as `int` or `list`, there is no way to create additional class attributes for them (which is obviously a desirable behavior) :

```
>>> int.x = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    int.x = 0
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

but if you create your own custom class, this restriction is not actived by default, so anybody may create additional class attributes in it

```
class foo(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2

>>> foo.c = 3
>>> print(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)
1 2 3
```

I know that the `__slots__` class attribute is one solution (among others) to forbid creation of unwanted **instance** attributes, but what is the process to forbid unwanted **class** attributes, as done in the built-in classes ?

Comment: You'd could use a *metaclass* with `__slots__`

Comment: @juanpa: I've tried such an approach, but I couldn't see any difference with creating `__slots__` directly in the initial class. Which means that I could still create new class attributes. Could you post some code snippet to illustrate your idea ?

Comment: Here's one way, using metaclasses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376404/prevent-creating-new-attributes-for-class-or-module/59376655#59376655

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: Hey, this looks like a very clear step in the right direction ! Do you know if built-in classes use that exact process, or are there some alternatives ? I guess that the implementation is different after doing the following test: when performing simple derivation from a built-in class, this feature is lost for the derived class, but when derivating the `A` class from your example, the derivated class is still frozen...

Comment: No, the built-in classes are implemented in C (for CPython) and setting attributes for them is controlled by this mechanism: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118488/how-are-built-in-types-protected-from-overwriting-assigning-to-their-methods

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: Wooow : fast, direct and clear ! So this explains that the "frozen" behavior is not transmitted to derived classes. Python guru you are indeed !

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: It would be nice if you could write an answer that summarizes your comments, so as I can validate it and offer you the bounty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should play with [metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses). It can define the behavior of your class instead of its instances.

The comment from [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361832/how-to-forbid-creation-of-new-class-attributes-in-python/59412709?noredirect=1#comment105012599_59361832) refers to another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376655/4373898) with the following code snippet:

```py
class FrozenMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        inst = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, {"_FrozenMeta__frozen": False, **dct})
        inst.__frozen = True
        return inst
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self.__frozen and not hasattr(self, key):
            raise TypeError("I am frozen")
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

class A(metaclass=FrozenMeta):
    a = 1
    b = 2

A.a = 2
A.c = 1 # TypeError: I am frozen
```

Comment: I also guess that the solution has something to do with metaclass, but couldn't find any snippet that shows how to get this behavior

Comment: Thanks for pasting the link provided by Patrick. As I said in my comment above, this implementation seems to differ from the one used in built-in classes, because the frozen behavior is inherited in one case, but not inherited in the other case.

Comment: @sciroccorics What do you mean by "inherited"?

Comment: When defining `class B(A): pass` and trying `B.c = 5 --> I'm frozen`. But when defining `class C(int): pass` and trying `C.c = 5 --> OK`. In other words, the "frozen" behavior of `A` is transmitted to `B` but the "frozen" behavior of `int` is not transmitted to `C`.

Answer (score 1):

@AlexisBRENON's answer works but if you want to emulate the behavior of a built-in class, where subclasses are allowed to override attributes, you can set the `__frozen` attribute to `True` only when the `bases` argument is empty:

```
class FrozenMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        inst = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, {"_FrozenMeta__frozen": False, **dct})
        inst.__frozen = not bases
        return inst
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self.__frozen and not hasattr(self, key):
            raise TypeError("I am frozen")
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

class A(metaclass=FrozenMeta):
    a = 1
    b = 2

class B(A):
    pass

B.a = 2
B.c = 1 # this is OK
A.c = 1 # TypeError: I am frozen
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see `built-in/extension type` you are dealing with an object that was not created in Python.  The `built-in` types of CPython were created with `C`, for example, and so the extra behavior of assigning new attributes was simply not written in.

You see similar behavior with `__slots__`:

```
>>> class Huh:
...    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

>>> class Hah(Huh):
...    pass

>>> Huh().c = 5   # traceback
>>> Hah().c = 5   # works
```

As far as making Python classes immutable, or at least unable to have new attributes defined, a `metaclass` is the route to go -- although anything written in pure Python will be modifiable, it's just a matter of how much effort it will take:

```
>>> class A(metaclass=FrozenMeta):
...     a = 1
...     b = 2

>>> type.__setattr__(A, 'c', 9)
>>> A.c
9
```

A more complete metaclass:

```
class Locked(type):
    "support various levels of immutability"
    #
    def __new__(metacls, cls_name, bases, clsdict, create=False, change=False, delete=False):
        cls = super().__new__(metacls, cls_name, bases, {
                "_Locked__create": True,
                "_Locked__change": True,
                "_Locked__delete": True,
                **clsdict,
                })
        cls.__create = create
        cls.__change = change
        cls.__delete = delete
        return cls
    #
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        if hasattr(cls, name):
            if cls.__change:
                super().__setattr__(name, value)
            else:
                raise TypeError('%s: cannot modify %r' % (cls.__name__, name))
        elif cls.__create:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError('%s: cannot create %r' % (cls.__name__, name))
    #
    def __delattr__(cls, name):
        if not hasattr(cls, name):
            raise AttributeError('%s: %r does not exist' % (cls.__name__, name))
        if not cls.__delete or name in (
                '_Locked__create', '_Locked__change', '_Locked_delete',
                ):
            raise TypeError('%s: cannot delete %r' % (cls.__name__, name))
        super().__delattr__(name)
```

and in use:

```
>>> class Changable(metaclass=Locked, change=True):
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
... 
>>> Changable.a = 9
>>> Changable.c = 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: Changable: cannot create 'c'
>>> del Changable.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: Changable: cannot delete 'b'
```

Comment: This isn't quite accurate - you can't set new attributes on instances of a typical built-in class because the data structures and hooks for that just weren't written in, but you can't set new attributes on *the class objects themselves* because there's a specific check in `type.__setattr__` for built-in classes.

Comment: (Specifically, [this check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/typeobject.c#L3280).)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: If that check were removed, would we then be able to add attributes to built-in classes, or would Python crash?

Comment: There'd be problems if you tried to mess with "core" attributes like `__new__` or `__setattr__`, but I think adding new attributes would work fine. (I think you might have problems with subinterpreters or with calling `Py_Initialize` after `Py_Finalize` or a few other unusual cases.)