# Prevent creating new attributes for class or module

Tags: python

I saw this question on SO [Prevent creating new attributes outside **init**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603502/prevent-creating-new-attributes-outside-init) which shows how to prevent adding new attributes to objects of classes.

I wanted the same behaviour for the overall class or even the complete loaded module.

Example class:

```
class Klass:
     a = 0
     b = 1
```

Another module:

```
from Klass import Klass

Klass.c = 2 # this should raise an error
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to prevent modifying the class itself, you can create a metaclass that defines the `__setattr__` method for the class.

```
class FrozenMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        inst = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, {"_FrozenMeta__frozen": False, **dct})
        inst.__frozen = True
        return inst
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self.__frozen and not hasattr(self, key):
            raise TypeError("I am frozen")
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

class A(metaclass=FrozenMeta):
    a = 1
    b = 2

A.a = 2
A.c = 1 # TypeError: I am frozen
```

Comment: This works as expected for the class! Too bad, there isn't something for the whole module

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668273/208880) for a  way to make a class be a module.

Answer (score -1):

The answer with **slots** would be the Pythonic way to do it.

```
class Klass:
    __slots__ = ['a', 'b']

    def __init__(self, a=0, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

```
>>> k = klass.Klass()
>>> k.a
0
>>> k.b
1
>>> k.c = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Klass' object has no attribute 'c'
>>>
```

Comment: But you can still do Klass.c=2 and then k will also have c

Comment: `__slots__` were not designed to prevent attribute creation, that is merely a side-effect.