# Best design decision to avoid assigning to undefined class attributes

Tags: python, oop, attributes, undefined

Consider the following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.historical = 5

t = Test()

# correct
print(t.historical)

# ops .. I made a mistake!
# an attribute error is thrown
#print(t.history)

# let's redefine the variable

# correct!
t.historical = 10

# ops ... I made a mistake!
t.history = 15 # <-- I want Python to throw an exception here

print(t.historical)
print(t.history)
```

In this code, I made a mistake: I assigned to `history` while the correct attribute name was `historical`.

How can I have Python throw an exception when I assign to `history`?

What is the best design decision to achieve this?

Comment: Implement `__setattr__` or use `__slots__`?

Comment: You can specify `__slots__ = 'historical',`, note that particular care must be taken if you intend on using inheritance. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376404/prevent-creating-new-attributes-for-class-or-module or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603502/prevent-creating-new-attributes-outside-init ?